# sqlite via c++, opening multiple sqlite files

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

How do I connect multiple sqlite files into a single sqlite3* handle, in C/C++?  I'm thinking it's possible considering there's a command called ATTACH, but do not know how to do so in C++.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (thanks to Robert)

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "ATTACH 'C:/tmp/tmp.sqlite' as mytmp");
```

Comment: you should bind that variable. What if the path contains a `'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the `ATTACH DATABASE` SQL command:

```
ATTACH path_to_database AS database-name
```

You can then refer to tables in the attached database as:

```
database-name.table-name
```

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html