# How can I merge many SQLite databases into a file or database?

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013

- I have multiples databases with the same table name. Is there any SQL command or API to merge multiple databases.

Comment: Please be more specific, preferably following the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. Do the tables with the same name all have the same schemas?  Do any of the databases have tables with other names? What have you tried? Have you considered using the ATTACH command? Writing the tables out as CSV files? ????

Comment: Perhaps *this* would do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592292/sqlite-via-c-opening-multiple-sqlite-files it does not merge but allows you to query them together

Comment: @peak. I tried writing the tables into CSV files by using this command sqlite3 -header -csv c:/sqlite/Database1.db "select * from demo;" > demo.csv. Every time a new file is created to perform write operations.

Comment: @santhosh - just looking at your example you're using in the comment above, to append to a file in dos - you'd use '>>' not '>' ... I'm not sure about the rest of your line and to be honest I'm not sure if you want to copy all the tables into one backup or another database using different names for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume to perform a join between a table that is in database A, to a table that is in database B

```
SELECT *
FROM A.table1 t1 JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column2 = t1.column1;
```

cheers